# network configuration on my ubuntu machine

Tags: networking

I recently created an instance and wanted to see the network configuration. Does anyone know how is can run ifconfig to obtain this info? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As ifconfig is being deprecated, please use the `ip` command. A good starting point would be `ip addr`.

From `man ip`

```
ip addr
           Shows addresses assigned to all network interfaces.
```